# How can I get the extension of a file which doesn't have on?

Tags: php, file

I have some images in directory: `c:/images/`. For example:

- 1.jpg
- 1.png
- 2.gif
- 3.jpg

And I have only image name  **without extension**, I know some images exists in `c:/images/` with names like: `1, 2, 3, ...` and I don't know the extensions of these.

How can get the extension of a file which doesn't have one?

I tried to use:

```
var_dump(pathinfo ('c:/images/1'));
```

But this returns only:

```
array(3) { ["dirname"]=> string(3) "c:\images\" ["basename"]=> string(1) "1" ["filename"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Comment: I thought the file is `1.jpg` not `1`-> `c:/images/1` ?!

Comment: i do not know extension of file i know only filename

Comment: Ah so, what would be the expected results with your files? `.jpg and .png` ?

Comment: You can't find the extension. The only way is to analize binary file data, if you know they are images. But this is very hard task, because there are a lot of image types. In more of them the image type is coded into binary file body, but anyway it is hard task.

Comment: What is it supposed to give you back if you have both `1.jpg` and `1.png` like your example? Chances are you'll need to use something like `glob` - `glob('C:\Images\1.*');`

Answer (score 1):

[getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/function.getimagesize.php) returns (besides other information) the MIME type of the image. So use

```
var_dump(getimagesize('c:/images/1'));
```

and you will get the MIME type in the array element `mime`. E.g. `image/jpeg` or `image/png`.

There's also the faster fundtion [exif_imagetype()](http://php.net/manual/function.exif-imagetype.php) but this function only returns an integer of the MIME type. The table to match the possible return values to an image type can be found in the PHP manual.

Comment: for 1.jpg and 1.png how do work `getimagesize('c:/images/1')` ?

Comment: no,no say error `failed to open stream: No such file or directory in`

Comment: How can get the extension of a file which doesn't have one?

Comment: If you get "failed to open stream: No such file or directory in" the file doesn't exist. You probably have an error in your code. For your other question: Files don't have an "extension", they have a MIME type and the extension helps some operating systems to find the correct MIME type. If the element `mime` of the array returned by `getimagesize()` is `image/jpeg`, the extension would be `.jpg`

Comment: It would by nice of the downvoter to explain why I've got downvoted.

Comment: because `getimagesize('c:/images/1')` say error `failed to open stream: No such file or directory in`

Comment: If getimagesize returns this error, the file 'c:/images/1' doesn't exist. Check the path

Answer (score 0):

If you have it, [`finfo_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) can return a file's mime type:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
var_dump(finfo_file($finfo, '/var/www/favicon.ico'));
```

Will print:

> string(12) "image/x-icon"

Extensions don't mean much on the web. Browsers and (web)servers don't really use them. They look at the mime type. A browser will detect a JPEG named `image.png` as JPEG.

Comment: you try with `var_dump(finfo_file($finfo, '/var/www/favicon'));` this say error

Comment: How can get the extension of a file which doesn't have one?

Comment: @mhkyazd You can't get the extension of a file that doesn't have an extension... obviously. What's the error you get? Change the path to your path.